# chart.js - Common time axis with different datapoints

Tags: time, chart.js, axis

I have 2 sensors that are read in different intervals. I need to display all the values in a chart.js chart, but the problem I am facing is that since the sensors are not read at the same time they have different time values. i was expecting them to be displayed anyway, since they are on a time basis..

is there a way to draw them on the same chart with proper time values?

here is some sample data:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b56ad3/4/1

******EDIT******

I made a test with a time-chart and it sort of works. the values are displayed correctly. but when i hover the image, in the info box i do not see the vlaues of each dataset that has a value in that region, rather i see the x-th value of that dataset. this means that if a dataset has more values than the other or starts later, i cannot see the current value at a given time for all charts. can this be changed? The green arrow in the image is the mouse. the red arrows are the values of the other two datasets that is returned...

[image]

Comment: You can use a time axis: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.4.0/axes/cartesian/time.html

Comment: @LeeLenalee i tried it and updated the question up there.. thanks

Comment: @LeeLenalee never mind, found it with interaction mode. i had index instaed of X. please post it as answer so i can accept it.